# ReactJS - TypeError: this.state.user.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
   state = {user:[]}

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://a99d12de.ngrok.io/api/Docs')
      .then(res => {
        const user = res.data;
        this.setState({user});
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        alert(error);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> names</h1>
        <ul>{this.state.user.map(person => <li>{person.data.fname}</li>)}</ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Please correct my mistakes.. I am just trying to rectify some data from server/url.I dont know why the map function is not defined.

Comment: console this.state.user in your render method to make sure it is not undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios is wrapping the response in an object that has a `data` property. So I guess you have to do something like this:

```
axios.get('http://a99d12de.ngrok.io/api/Docs')
    .then(res => {
        // axios wrapped the data in a response object with a data property
        const data = res.data; 
        // Your API also wrapped the data in a response object with a data property :)
        const user = data.data; 
        this.setState({user});
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        alert(error);
    })
}
```

See the axios docs [here](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){

let array = this.state.user || []

return(
    <div>
        <h1> names</h1>
            <ul>
              {array.map((item,index) => ( <li key={index}> {item.fname}</li> ))}
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. OP is already trying to set an initial state for `user` so your check is unnecessary as it should always be an array.

Comment: he tryind do this `person.data.fname` need this  `person.fname` because `const user = res.data;` You can check response.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your response data is `JSON String`, you must use `JSON.parse(user)`

```
(res => {
    const user = JSON.parse(res.data);
    this.setState({user});
})
```